# gsub a repetitive pattern of dimensions in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I want to `gsub` a pattern of dimensions mentioned in a string in R. For example:

```
"16 x 13 x 12 inch box"
"1x2x3 pipe" 
"123x 23 x334 asd"
```

Expected output:

```
"inch box"
"pipe"
"asd"
```

What I have got so far is this expression: `[0-9]*\\s*x\\s*`. How can I make it a repetitive pattern match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A part of the pattern can be repeated with quantifiers. If you need to quantifier a group of patterns, use a *grouping construct* and apply the quantifier to the construct.

You may use

```
sub("^[0-9]+(?:\\s*x\\s*[0-9]+)+\\s*", "", x)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xdzoz1/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:`  - start of a non-capturing group matching the following consecutive subpatterns:

  - `\\s*` -0+ whitespaces
  - `x` - an `x`
  - `\\s*` -0+ whitespaces
  - `[0-9]+`
- `)+` - ...1 or more times
- `\\s*` -0+ whitespaces.

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/bKUgqh):

```
x <- c("16 x 13 x 12 inch box", "1x2x3 pipe", "123x 23 x334 asd")
sub("^[0-9]+(?:\\s*x\\s*[0-9]+)+\\s*", "", x)
## => [1] "inch box" "pipe"     "asd"
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do `sub` to match the characters (`.*`) followed by one or more numbers (`\\d+`) followed by spaces (`\\s+`) and replace it with blank (`"`)

```
sub(".*\\d+\\s+", "", v1)
#[1] "inch box" "pipe"     "asd"
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative regex that groups digits "\d" and "x" allowing for the lack of certain characters with "?" and the possibility of missing final digit with "*" the wrapping of this pattern with "()+" allows the pattern to repeat indefinitely.

```
sub("(\\d+ ?x ?\\d* ?)+", "", x)
[1] "inch box" "pipe"     "asd"
```